# Flutter Dio sending blank request on Laravel Server

Tags: laravel, flutter, laravel-7, dio

**Flutter Code:**

Normal Data JSON object

```
var data = {
    'society_id': widget.societyId,
    'name': _currentCategory,
    'details': txtDescription.text,
    'type': "Society Residential Complaint"
};
```

FormData for Dio Request

```
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    'society_id': widget.societyId,
    'name': _currentCategory,
    'details': txtDescription.text,
    'type': "Society Residential Complaint"
});
if (selectedFile != null) {
    String path = selectedFile.path;
    String imagename = selectedFile.path.split('/').last;
    print("Photo Selected");
    formData.files.add(
      MapEntry(
        "photos[]",
        await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          path,
          filename: imagename.toString(),
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Function which will make Dio Post Request

```
Future raiseComplaint(FormData formData, data) async {
    await _getToken();
    String requestUrl = serverURL + '/complaint/add';
    print("Sending Req: $requestUrl");
    print("--- complaint details: $formData");
    print("--- complaint details: $data");

    try {
      dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $_accessToken";
      Response serverResponse = await dio.post(requestUrl, data: formData);
      var response = _returnResponse(serverResponse);
      print("Recieving Res: $requestUrl");
      print(response);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
}
```

Call Request

```
var response = await raiseComplaint(formData, data);
```

Problem:
from raiseComplaint() function if I send normal json object, I'm receiving all the parameters. I need attachment files as well, so using the Dio FormData object. FormData object wrapping all the parameters in `fields` map and attachments in `files` map, which I am unable to receive on server.

[image: FormData Object 1]

[image: FormData Object 2]

On (Laravel) server I am not getting any parameters or files from the request due to laravel validation fails. I searched the [Dio package documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/) but didn't found any much help. We need to move with the Dio request, so please if anyone stuck with this error in past, help appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should be using `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json` since you are sending a file.

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria Thanks for reply, we tried that as well, but from mobile application no data is getting released, so we couldnt get anything on server side. I logged PHP $_POST & $_FILES array but both are empty.

Comment: any updates? Having the same problem